Whenever I try running the server for django in my virtual enviroment it doesn't work
Whenever I try running the server for django in my virtual enviroment it doesn't work.
Example:
python manage.py runserver

Replies:
NameError: name 'include' is not defined

I know it's referencing my urls.py where I say path('hello/', include("hello.urls"))
but I need that for me to do what I'm doing
I tried looking on stack overflow, youtube, fixing it, trying something my ide said would work. All I wanted it to do was run a server that I could copy and paste the url for and would be able to access it but no.

include is a django function.  You have to import it.  from django.urls import include
